# Finding equivalent metrics in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that do not preserve bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am looking for a counterexample for the claim that equivalent metrics $d$, $d'$ preserve bounded sets.

I know that in Euclidean spaces set $X$ is compact iff $X$ is closed and bounded. Given that closedness and compactness are preserved under equivalent distances, shouldn't that mean that boundedness should be as well?

Could therefore someone help me building such counterexample, preferrably in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: There's always a bounded metric $d'=min(1,d)$ which is equivalent to any given metric.

Comment: Another brain tease in a similar spirit: Equivalent metrics have the same convergent sequences (you use this when showing that they preserve closedness), however they need not share the same Cauchy sequences.